# Как обновлять проекции у которых первичный ключ отличается от ключа агрегата потока в cqrs event sourcing?

Tags: c#, cqrs

Пример событий:

```
class UserCreated
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

class UserPhoneNumberChanged
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string NewPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

При обработке события `UserCreated` создаётся проекция и сохраняется в хранилище (тут всё просто).

Но при обработке `UserPhoneNumberChanged` возникает проблема с поиском нужной проекции если для проекции используется `PhoneNumber` как первичный ключ (`PhoneNumber` нужен для запроса по ключу).

Как обновлять (находить) проекции у которых первичный ключ отличается от ключа агрегата потока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решений всего два:

1. Добавлять в событие дополнительные данные для поиска проекций, но проблема в том, что невозможно предусмотреть какие данные могут понадобиться в дальнейшем.
2. Создавать таблицу с индексами (id проекции -> id потока событий агрегата)